# RestController with Spring WebFlux :Required parameter is not present

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I wrote a Rest Controller Demo with Spring WebFlux,it can't run correctly, source code as follows:

```
@RestController
public class Demo{
    @PostMapping(value = "test2")
    public Integer getHashCode(@RequestParam("parameters") String parameters){
        return parameters.hashCode();
    }
}
```

I used Postman to test it, the returning:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2018-05-07T07:19:05.303+0000",
    "path": "/test2",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": "Required String parameter 'parameters' is not present"
}
```

[image]

dependencies:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

> I wrote the same controller demo with Spring boot(v2.0.1.RELEASE), it can run correctly. Why can't it run correctly in Spring Webflux?

Comment: How can I get the `parameters` value without changing the http request?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [described in the reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-ann-requestparam), there is a slight behavior difference between Servlet-based apps (Spring MVC) and Spring WebFlux with regards to request parameters.

In Spring WebFlux, `@RequestParam` will only bind query parameters. In your case, your HTTP request is not providing such a query parameter and your method signature does not mark it as optional.

Looking at your Postman screenshot, it looks like you meant to bind HTTP form data to that argument, then you should probably take a look at [command objects](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-ann-modelattrib-method-args) instead.

Comment: I change the code to `public Integer getHashCode(@RequestParam("parameters") Optional<String> parameters)`, why the `parameters.isPresent()` returns false?

Comment: did you send the query parameter with your request URL?

Comment: If I don't send the query parameter with request URL,are there any other methods to response the request correctly?

Comment: if you don't send the query parameter, then declaring that argument as optional is the right way to go.

Comment: I declare it  as optional, but the `parameters.isPresent()` returns false.

Comment: In other words, how can I get the `parameters` value without changing the http request?

Answer (score 2):

As @brian-clozel mentioned in his answer Spring WebFlux doesn't support binding from the form data and multiparts by the `@RequestParam` at the moment (there is an open issue [SPR-16190](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/20738)).

An altenative approach might be to inject `ServerWebExchange` and access its [`getFormData()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/server/ServerWebExchange.html#getFormData--):

```
@PostMapping(value = "test2")
public Mono<Integer> getHashCode(ServerWebExchange exchange){
    return exchange.getFormData().map(formData -> {
        if (formData.containsKey("parameters")) {
            return formData.getFirst("parameters").hashCode();
        } else {
            throw new ServerWebInputException("Required parameter 'parameters' is not present");
        }
    });
}
```

(But to be honest, the approach with the `@ModelAttribute` and dedicated model class for the form data looks much easier)

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the request as `x-www-form-urlencoded` instead of form-data ? I guess Spring webflux only takes request parameters that are query params and not the form data.

**Update :**
I just tried the same code with webflux and java 10. I can clearly get right response.. So the webflux and the form-data doesn't have at impact whatsoever.

[image: post-request]

Comment: It also occurs that `Required String parameter 'parameters' is not present`

Comment: I tried your code and it just works as expected. Can you re-check if your code and the deployed code in tomcat is same?

Comment: It can run correctly when it deployed in tomcat. Your code is deployed in netty server?@Karthik

Comment: `Netty started on port(s): 20000`  `Failed to handle request [POST http://localhost:20000/test2]: Response status 400 with reason "Required String parameter 'parameters' is not present"`

Comment: No :( Tomcat. That's weird but we zeroed down to Netty? Why would it make difference? What version of netty? can u try latest?